# Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'Item' operands

Tags: ios, binary, tuples, operator-keyword, swift5

In swift 5, I'm not sure what this error mean: "Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'Item' operands"

I'm trying to find the index of tuple in an array of tuples and only checking the item and not the qty.

This is the tuple array I'm checking in:

`var items = [(item: Item, qty: Int)]()`

This is the function giving me the error (the second line):

```
    private func find(item: Item) -> Int? {
    let index = items.firstIndex(where: { $0.item == item } )

    return index
}
```

}

How can I rewrite this to remove this error?
Thanks

Comment: It helps if you add a tag for the language in which you're coding. It helps get it to the attention of people who can help. Please [edit] to do so.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable

Comment: Your `Item` doesn't know how to compare itself with other `Item`s

Comment: your `Item` should conform `Equatable` protocol.

Answer (score 0):

The type 'Item' is not comparable because swift does not know how to equate it. It would solve the error to add a string value, such as a name, to the `Item` class/struct, then compare said values. I have run into this issue before, and giving the instances an id to reference them by is my solution.